# Is there a tool that converts git diff output to SQL INSERT and DELETE statements?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git

I'm working on a WordPress site by doing development on my laptop and then deploying the changes by pushing with git to the server.  This works great for files and I want to do the same thing with content changes to the database.

My first iteration at solving the problem used git hooks to dump the database using `mysqldump` before commits and then restoring the dumps after checkouts.  This works but drops and recreates the whole database each time.  This is not OK because WordPress is also making changes automatically to the database that I want to keep, like records of which products are sold, so I don't want the whole thing dropped and restored every checkout.

I'm thinking a better solution would be to continue dumping the database during commits and then for checkouts use a new tool that reads the output of `git diff HEAD^` and converts it to INSERT and DELETE SQL statements fed to `mysql`.  That way the database would be patched incrementally with my changes while preserving changes made by others (such as WordPress).  Example:

git diff:

```
 (83,NULL,550,'TI-99/4A','',0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0),
-(85,NULL,2000,'Banana Jr. 6000','',0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0),
+(85,NULL,2000,'Banana Jr. 6000 (now with tint control!)','',0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0),
 (88,NULL,150,'Symbolics 3645','',0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0),
```

converted to SQL:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_yak_product` WHERE `post_id`='85';
INSERT INTO `wp_yak_product` VALUES (85,NULL,2000,'Banana Jr. 6000 (now with tint control!)','',0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0);
```

I've searched around and can't find anything like this.  I'm considering writing it myself.

Does something like this exist?  Is this a good or a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a possible approach:

I dump the database into a different file for each table:

```
wp_commentmeta.sql
wp_comments.sql
wp_links.sql
```

etc.

Perhaps I could separate the tables into categories of content vs. bookkeeping, like the distinction between the [`usr` and `var` directories in Unix](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/fhs), and add the bookkeeping tables to my `.gitignore` so they're not clobbered when I update the content.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that type of tool does not exist. The best option that I know of to produce similar output would be to use the "[Synchronize Model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html)" functionality in [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

That said, I would recommend tracking the changes that you make in your development database in a SQL file, checked into git, which can be executed on your production server.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  When you recommend tracking the changes in my development database, do you mean manually?

Comment: It sounds like a pain, but that's what I typically do. I have used version numbers to execute SQL changes depending on what version you are starting from and going to, but this largely is going to depending on the scope of your changes (a few, a lot), size of your team (you, a couple, a lot, the world), and personal preference.